# Update and save with one button in List view and delete button doesn't work in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I Have this scenario where name,designation, joining year are saved in database. I want to update with save button. I am facing some problem.

1. when double click on list view update mode is on but data doesn't update.
2. delete doesn't work.
3. After saving, newly saved data is not reloading on list view.It only reload after re-run the project

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace Student_Information
{
    public partial class TeacherInformation : Form
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-VTPQ9MQ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StudentDB;Integrated Security=True");
        int Id = 0;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter data;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        public TeacherInformation()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 


        }

        private void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EnableDisable();

        }

        private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            try
            {
                if (saveButton.Text == "Save")
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("AddTeacher", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[3];

                    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@TeacherName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    param[0].Value = nameTextBox.Text.Trim();

                    param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Designation", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    param[1].Value = designationComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

                    param[2] = new SqlParameter("@JoiningDate", SqlDbType.Date);
                    param[2].Value = joiningDateTimePicker.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Insert Done", "Insert Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                }

                else if (saveButton.Text =="Update")
                {

                    cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateTeacher", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[4];

                    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
                    param[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Id);

                    param[1] = new SqlParameter("@TeacherName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    param[1].Value = nameTextBox.Text.Trim();

                    param[2] = new SqlParameter("@Designation", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    param[2].Value = designationComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

                    param[3] = new SqlParameter("@JoiningDate", SqlDbType.Date);
                    param[3].Value = joiningDateTimePicker.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Update Done", "Update Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("something is Wrong");
                }

                Clear();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void deleteButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteTeacher", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];

                param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
                param[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Id);

                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Done", "Delete Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                Clear();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }


        public void EnableDisable()
        {
            saveButton.Enabled = true;
            deleteButton.Enabled = true;
            nameTextBox.Enabled = true;
            designationComboBox.Enabled= true;
            joiningDateTimePicker.Enabled = true;

        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            saveButton.Enabled = false;
            deleteButton.Enabled = false;
            nameTextBox.Enabled = false;
            designationComboBox.Enabled = false;
            joiningDateTimePicker.Enabled = false;
            newButton.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Clear()
        {
            nameTextBox.Text = "";
            designationComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
            joiningDateTimePicker.Text = "";
        }

        private void TeacherInformation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SearchDataGridView();
            Clear();

            saveButton.Enabled = false;
            deleteButton.Enabled = false;
            newButton.Enabled = true;
            nameTextBox.Enabled = false;
            designationComboBox.Enabled = false;
            joiningDateTimePicker.Enabled = false;
        }

        public void SearchDataGridView()
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter data = new SqlDataAdapter("SearchTeacherByName", conn);
            data.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            data.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeacherName", searchTextBox.Text.Trim());
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            data.Fill(dt);
          teacherListView.View = View.Details;
          teacherListView.FullRowSelect = true;

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(row["Id"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(row["TeacherName"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(row["Designation"].ToString());
                listitem.SubItems.Add(row["JoiningDate"].ToString());
                teacherListView.Items.Add(listitem);

            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SearchDataGridView();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void teacherListView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                if (teacherListView.SelectedItems.Count > -1)
                   // return;

            Id = Convert.ToInt32(teacherListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].ToString());
            nameTextBox.Text =teacherListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
            designationComboBox.Text =teacherListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
            joiningDateTimePicker.Value =Convert.ToDateTime(teacherListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text.ToString());
            saveButton.Text = "Update";
            deleteButton.Enabled = true;
            }


        }

        private void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Reset();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: May i know why you have written "solved" before question title

Comment: Your question is unclear at best. If it's solved, either delete the question or post an answer. Otherwise it will not help other people looking for a way to solve similar problems.

Comment: I provide solution below comment. 
TIa

Comment: I've rolled this back to the last good question state. Please always add answers below, rather than merging them into the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1 and 2 are solved.

update and delete works fine.
problem was i didn't pass primary key 'Id' to update and delete button.

I Update teacherListView event as below. and i works.

```
 private void teacherListView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                if (teacherListView.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
                    return;

            Id = Convert.ToInt32(teacherListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text.ToString());
            nameTextBox.Text =teacherListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
            designationComboBox.Text =teacherListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
            joiningDateTimePicker.Value =Convert.ToDateTime(teacherListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text.ToString());
            saveButton.Text = "Update";
            deleteButton.Enabled = true;
            }


        }
```